# Cannot select launch configuration when exporting Scala from Eclipse as JAR

Tags: eclipse, scala, build, export, executable-jar

I have a Scala project in Eclipse and I want to export it as a Jar file in order to deploy it elsewhere. I can run it in Eclipse without errors.

**Problem:**

I right click my project and select Export - Java - Runnable JAR file. I should select a launch configuration but the launch configuration menu is blank.

**What have I tried:**

1. I have read this thread ["Launch Configuration" Shows up Blank When Trying to Export Runnable Jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224364/launch-configuration-shows-up-blank-when-trying-to-export-runnable-jar)

It was advised that I should run my main method to create a launch configuration. However, I have run it many times already.

2. I have tried exporting it as a normal JAR. However, then the main method selection part is blank. This is probably caused by the same issue.
3. In some thread, I read that it can cause problems if I have two main methods. I commented the other one away and I still have the problem.
4. I have tried to clean project.

**Additional information:**

-I have added scala-swing and scala-parser-combinators to Referenced Libraries

-Here is a screenshot of my filetree:

There is a small yellow warning triange. But it doesn't have any text on it. Edit: I found out I can check it on the Problems tab. It says that there are two deprecation warnings.

[image]

[image]

Selecting scala-swing and scala-parser-combinations removed the warning triangle, but did not solve the issue. Originally only the src folder was selected. I also tried selecting them all.